# Trying to create a SurfaceMesh, but having connectivity problems

Tags: c++, cgal

I am trying to create a SurfaceMesh to pass to the cgal parameterize functions, but im having problems with the connectivity. I have a list of vertices and indices, and i am using the following code to generate the surfacemesh:

```c
SurfaceMesh mesh;

//add vertices
QVector<vertex_descriptor> vertex_descriptors = QVector<vertex_descriptor>(m_vertices.size());

for (int i = 0; i < m_vertices.size(); ++i) {
    _Vertex v = m_vertices[i];
    vertex_descriptors[i] = mesh.add_vertex(Point_3(v.getX(), v.getY(), v.getZ()));
}

QVector<face_descriptor> face_descriptors = QVector<face_descriptor>(m_indices.size() / 3);
//add surfaces
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m_indices.size(); ++i) {
    vertex_descriptor x = vertex_descriptors[m_indices[i++]];
    vertex_descriptor y = vertex_descriptors[m_indices[i++]];
    vertex_descriptor z = vertex_descriptors[m_indices[i]];
    face_descriptor tmp = mesh.add_face(x,y,z);
    face_descriptors[j++] = tmp;
}
```

The mesh appears to be valid, but the border halfedges seem to be messed up. TO find the problem, i tried iterating over the Halfedges like so:

```c
for(vertex_descriptor v: mesh.vertices())
{
    qInfo() << "Check Vertex " << v;

    for(halfedge_descriptor hi : halfedges_around_target(v, mesh))
    {
        qInfo() << "check halfedge" << hi;
        if ( mesh.face(hi) == SurfaceMesh::null_face())
        {
           qInfo() << "BORDER FOUND" << hi;
        }
    }
}
```

This returns a repeating sequence of:

```
Check Vertex  0
check halfedge 1
BORDER FOUND 1
check halfedge 4
Check Vertex  1
check halfedge 3
BORDER FOUND 3
check halfedge 0
Check Vertex  2
check halfedge 5
BORDER FOUND 5
check halfedge 2
Check Vertex  3
check halfedge 7
BORDER FOUND 7
check halfedge 10
Check Vertex  4
check halfedge 9
BORDER FOUND 9
check halfedge 6
```

So apparenty the faces created by mesh.add_face() arent properly connected to existing halfedges and are standing independend of each other. The mesh wont be able to be parameterized by cgal.

Ive tested several different meshes, even ones that are supposed to be closed and it still returns true for one of the vertex incident halfedges.

How can i create a properly connected SurfaceMesh?

Answer (score 2):

The Problem was, that reading my meshes directly from raw data caused them to have a lot of duplicate vertices, wich in turn messed up the connectivity.

if you call

CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::stitch_borders(mesh);

and mesh.collect_garbage() if needed it fixes the connectivity problem.